# How to test queues redis connection?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am using "**redis**" to mange my queues

phpunit.xml:

```xml
<server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="redis"/>
```

But in the following test the queue's connection name returns "**null**":

```php
 /** @test */
    public function is_pushed_to_queue()
    {
        Queue::fake();
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $user->notify(
            new EmailVerificationNotification($user)
        );

        $this->assertEquals(1, Queue::size());
        $this->assertEquals('redis', Queue::getConnectionName());// getConnectionName returns "null"
    }
```

phpunit error:

```
Failed asserting that null matches expected 'redis'.
```

How can I test the connection of the queues which is "**redis**"?

Comment: Have you tried "env" next to "server" in the XML configuration?